# The value of $\sigma_{X,Y}$?

Tags: distributions, covariance

Suppose we toss a coin $n$ times, we are interested in the number of 'tails' (which have probability $p$ of appearing), put $X$ the number of sucsess, and put $Y$ the number of fails. I know that $X$ and $Y$ both have a Binomial distribution with probabilities $p$ and $1-p$ (successively).

Now if $n$ is large enough, $X$ and $Y$ (which are dependent) can be seen as Normal distributed variables. I know that 
$$ X + Y \sim N(\mu_X + \mu_Y,\; \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2 + 2\sigma_{X,Y})$$
where $\mu_X=np$, $\mu_Y=n(1-p)$ and  $\sigma_{X}^2=\sigma_Y^2=np(1-p)$. What can we say about $\sigma_{X,Y}$? does it have a closed form like the mean and variance?

Comment: How about:  $X + Y = n$.  If $X$ is a tail, why do you call $Y$ a fail? In any event, why are you working with approximations?  You have not defined $\sigma_{X,Y}$

Comment: @wolfies, I just gave an example of two dependent variables, I'm interested in the distribution of $X+Y$ when both are dependent normal variables, the problem is in the covariance of $X$ and $Y$, $\sigma_{X,Y}$, does it have a closed form?

Comment: Yes, it has a closed form: $X+Y=n$ gives the distribution--which is Normal only in a degenerate sense.  Moreover, since $Y=n-X$, it is trivial to compute the covariance of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @whuber, is this right? $<X,Y>=<X,n-Y>=<X,n>-<X,X>=-var(X)$

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  As a check, note that $\sigma_X=\sigma_Y$ and since $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)=\operatorname{Var}(n)=0$, you must have $\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2+2\sigma_{XY}=0$, which you can solve for $\sigma_{XY}$.

Comment: @whuber, thank you very much, how do I mark this question as answered?